# How to print progress bar of R function without for loop?

Tags: r, function, progress

I have a function that takes a long time to run (involves many calculations in a large dataset). I want to include a progress bar to see if it's making progress. My function has no for loops; I don't understand how to add a progress bar if I don't have a for loop in the function.

I tried adding a for loop to get the progress bar to work, but it's just printing the progress bar without doing the calculations (I believe), i.e. when I print `result` I get `NULL`:

```
install.packages("svMisc")
require("svMisc")

# Test function
funct<-function(a,b,c)for (i in 0:101){
  progress(i, progress.bar=TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(0.01)
  x<-a*a
  y<-x+b
  z<-y/2
  if (i == 101) message("Done!")
}

result <- funct(-2.6e+70,-2.5e+121,6)
result
```

Feel free to suggest something other than `svMisc`.

Comment: Your example *is* doing the calculation in the function, just not returning it. Either move `z <-y/2` to the last line in the function, or add an explicit `return(z)` after the if statement

Comment: Either change suggested above also needs an extra set of braces

Comment: @Miff, please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, reporting the progress of a function will require a loop (or possibly a number of lines of code), as you've set out in your example. Your example *is* performing the calculations, it is just not returning them - remember that R functions return the value of the last calculation unless there is an explicit `return()` statement. In this case, the `message()` function returns `NULL`.

The minor modification to your code below demonstrates the expected behaviour of the progress bar, followed by `result` having the calculated value.

```
install.packages("svMisc")
require("svMisc")

# Test function
funct<-function(a,b,c){
  for (i in 0:101){
    progress(i, progress.bar=TRUE)
    Sys.sleep(0.01)
    x<-a*a
    y<-x+b
    z<-y/2
    if (i == 101) message("Done!")
  }
  return(z)
}

result <- funct(-2.6e+70,-2.5e+121,6)

#           0%---------25%---------50%---------75%--------100%
# Progress: ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
# Done!

result

# [1] 3.38e+140
```